# How can i get design doc of spring framework opensource projects

Tags: java, spring, open-source

I would like to understand the spring-projects code base

https://github.com/spring-projects
but i don't see any design doc for projects. 
How can i get the design doc?

Comment: What makes you think there are any? All the docs are either there or on the site or on the spring site.

Answer (score 1):

Each project follows different guidelines.  Things that vary between projects include:

1. Build Tool (Maven, Gradle, etc.)
2. Source Code Formatting (Checkstyle)
3. Monolithic Repo vs. Multi Repos (e.g. Spring Boot vs. Spring Cloud)
4. Issue Tracker (Jira, GitHub, etc.)

The best way to understand a particular project is:

1. Review the Source Code
2. Read the Documentation
3. Explore Issue Tracker
4. Join the Gitter Chat Room
5. Subscribe to the [Spring Blog](https://spring.io/blog)
6. Watch YouTube Videos